# How to implement my own ResNet with torch.nn.Sequential in Pytorch?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I want to implement a ResNet network (or rather, **residual blocks**) but I really want it to be in the sequential network form.

What I mean by sequential network form is the following:

```
## mdl5, from cifar10 tutorial
mdl5 = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict([
    ('pool1', nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)),
    ('relu1', nn.ReLU()),
    ('conv1', nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)),
    ('pool1', nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)),
    ('relu2', nn.ReLU()),
    ('conv2', nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)),
    ('relu2', nn.ReLU()),
    ('Flatten', Flatten()),
    ('fc1', nn.Linear(1024, 120)), # figure out equation properly
    ('relu4', nn.ReLU()),
    ('fc2', nn.Linear(120, 84)),
    ('relu5', nn.ReLU()),
    ('fc3', nn.Linear(84, 10))
]))
```

but of course with the NN lego blocks being “ResNet”.

I know the equation is something like:

[image]

but I am not sure how to do it in Pytorch AND Sequential. Sequential is key for me!

---

## Bounty:

I'd like to see an example with a fully connected net and where the BN layers would have to go (and the drop out layers would go too). Ideally on a toy example/data if possible.

---

Cross-posted:

- https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-have-residual-network-using-only-sequential-blocks/51541
- https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-does-one-implement-my-own-ResNet-with-torch-nn-Sequential-in-Pytorch
- https://www.reddit.com/r/pytorch/comments/uyyr28/how_to_implement_my_own_resnet_with/

Answer (score 16):

You can't do it solely using `torch.nn.Sequential` as it requires operations to go, as the name suggests, sequentially, while yours are parallel.

You could, in principle, construct your own `block` really easily like this:

```
import torch

class ResNet(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, module):
        super().__init__()
        self.module = module

    def forward(self, inputs):
        return self.module(inputs) + inputs
```

Which one can use something like this:

```
model = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size=7),
    # 32 filters in and out, no max pooling so the shapes can be added
    ResNet(
        torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Conv2d(32, 32, kernel_size=3),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
            torch.nn.Conv2d(32, 32, kernel_size=3),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
        )
    ),
    # Another ResNet block, you could make more of them
    # Downsampling using maxpool and others could be done in between etc. etc.
    ResNet(
        torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Conv2d(32, 32, kernel_size=3),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
            torch.nn.Conv2d(32, 32, kernel_size=3),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
        )
    ),
    # Pool all the 32 filters to 1, you may need to use `torch.squeeze after this layer`
    torch.nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(1),
    # 32 10 classes
    torch.nn.Linear(32, 10),
)
```

Fact being usually overlooked (without real consequences when it comes to shallowe networks) is that skip connection should be left **without** any nonlinearities like `ReLU` or convolutional layers and that's what you can see above (source: [Identity Mappings in Deep Residual Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.05027.pdf)).

Comment: is it not possible to have a "residual block" rather than wrapping the WHOLE network? Just some layers having skip connections?

Comment: You are only wrapping this "blue" connection, while providing shortcut purple. Sure, you could do it, but there are plethora of `ResNet` blocks and their variations, using this version you could use any of them easily.

Comment: like a plethora like in pytorch you mean? links? :)

Comment: [Here](https://towardsdatascience.com/an-overview-of-resnet-and-its-variants-5281e2f56035) are some, others are throughout arxiv, e.g. the one I have linked in my answer. Their common denominator is shortcut, not the `relu-conv-batch norm`.

Comment: The base class's __init__ must be called for this code to work. Add 
```super(ResNet, self).__init__()``` in ResNet's __init__ method.

Comment: @nithinsubbiah, doesn't need in recent python version because of new version of super